# Getting only most recent timestamp from a set of distinct values, so there are no repeats of 'distinct' values and only one timestamp

Tags: postgresql

We are working with database-stored post-Bro-processed network events from malware lab infections in order to populate a MISP instance with the data.  The underlying database system is PostgreSQL.

We have the code that updates the MISP side working fine, but because there's *tons* of repeat events with different timestamps, we can have data results in the thousands for a distinct pair of ip and port.

An example of values would be something like (note: datatypes are included with the header row in the table for clarity on the way this is stored in the SQL DB):

| ts (timestamp w/ timezone) | resp_h (inet) | resp_p (integer) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-05 07:37:50.869766 +00:00 | 52.254.114.69 | 443 |
| 2022-07-05 06:29:37.149036 +00:00 | 64.62.200.237 | 443 |
| 2022-07-05 06:29:24.205741 +00:00 | 64.62.200.237 | 443 |
| 2022-06-28 12:44:52.303022 +00:00 | 64.62.200.237 | 443 |
| ... |  |  |

This data is as 'distinct' as we can get it, selecting from our table as follows (note that `INFECTIONID` is an integer value that represents a specific infection ID in the system):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ts, resp_h, resp_p 
FROM bro_data WHERE infection=INFECTIONID 
  AND resp_h IS NOT NULL 
  AND resp_p IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ts DESC
```

Now, I am almost certain we can narrow this down further, but I'm not entirely sure how to.  What I'd like to do is narrow down the data list so that we get *one* record for each `resp_h` and `resp_p` value that has only one timestamp - the latest timestamp for a record.

Using the above three example values out of thousands, the desired results would be the return of exactly two values (again, datavalue types along with header for consistency with above table):

| ts (timestamp w/ timezone) | resp_h (inet) | resp_p (integer) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-05 07:37:50.869766 +00:00 | 52.254.114.69 | 443 |
| 2022-07-05 06:29:37.149036 +00:00 | 64.62.200.237 | 443 |

I'm not as SQL experienced as I am Python experienced, and I'd like to *not* have to preprocess the thousands of data values at the Python code that processes the data into the MISP events on our end.  Is there anyone who can help guide me with proper SQL search syntax to get only the desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you need always the latest timestamp then it should be:

```
SELECT max(ts) AS latest_ts, resp_h, resp_p
           FROM bro_data
           WHERE infection=INFECTIONID 
  AND resp_h IS NOT NULL 
  AND resp_p IS NOT NULL
          GROUP BY 2,3;
```

Comment: Unnecessary alias eliminated (it's automatically added by my code editor).

Comment: No worries, it was flagged as "unneeded" by DataGrip/PyCharm in my environment, and both ways worked :)  Thank you for your response too!

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
SELECT
   distinct on(resp_h, rsp_p) ts, resp_h, resp_p
FROM
   (SELECT 
      ts, resp_h, resp_p
   FROM 
      bro_data 
   WHERE 
      infection=INFECTIONID 
   AND 
      resp_h IS NOT NULL 
   AND 
      resp_p IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY 
      ts DESC)
   AS  
      ts_desc
```

Comment: Partial success, but ultimately fails the desired output - this returns an old timestamp for 62.62.200.237 in the data (there's timestamps as old as June 28 in there that I did not include for brevity sake in the examples) and not the latest timestamp value.  It does properly return single values of distinct `resp_h` and `resp_p`, but not the 'latest' timestamp value for the relevant `ts` field.  This is a lot closer to what is needed but not exactly what is needed, because the `ts` value is still not the latest timestamp (see updated example values in sample set in question)

Comment: Coffee consumed, hopefully more useful query. Basically I inverted the original query.

Comment: Updated way works, but so does the no-nested-selects that Pepe N O came up with in their answer.  Thank you for your input/effort though!

Comment: Obviously I did not consume enough coffee;)